# Spring OAuth2 SSO preflight request handling

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on

I am studying Spring OAuth and got some troubles with CORS and preflight requests, probably someone could help me.

As a base I took example project from "Cloud Native Java" book:
https://github.com/cloud-native-java/edge

For my question two parts are relevant: Gateway SSO service (greetings-client) and Authorization service (auth-service).

Here is SSO configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Sso
class SsoConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers( "/", "/app.js", "/login**", "/webjars/**").permitAll().anyRequest()
            .authenticated().and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll().and().csrf()
            .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
    }
}
```

Edge service has simple UI part. When called directly it tries to make a request to */user* endpoint, which is protected, to get Principal info.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <title>Edge Service</title>
    <meta name="description" content=""/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
    <base href="/"/>
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="/webjars/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="/webjars/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="/webjars/angularjs/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="home as home">

<div class="container" ng-show="!home.authenticated">
    <a href="/login">Login </a>
</div>

<div class="container" ng-show="home.authenticated">

    <!--1-->
    Logged in as:
    <b><span ng-bind="home.user"></span></b> <br/>

    Token:
    <b><span ng-bind="home.token"></span> </b><br/>

    Greeting from Zuul Route: <b>
    <span ng-bind="home.greetingFromZuulRoute"></span></b> <br/>

    Greeting from Edge Service (Feign):
    <b><span ng-bind="home.greetingFromEdgeService"></span></b><br/>
</div>

<!--2-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And javascript:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

//<1>
app.factory('oauth', function () {
    return {details: null, name: null, token: null};
});

app.run(['$http', '$rootScope', 'oauth', function ($http, $rootScope, oauth) {

    $http.get("/user").success(function (data) {

        oauth.details = data.userAuthentication.details;
        oauth.name = oauth.details.name;
        oauth.token = data.details.tokenValue;

        // <2>
        $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'bearer ' + oauth.token;

        // <3>
        $rootScope.$broadcast('auth-event', oauth.token);
    });
}]);

app.controller("home", function ($http, $rootScope, oauth) {

    var self = this;

    self.authenticated = false;

    // <4>
    $rootScope.$on('auth-event', function (evt, ctx) {
        self.user = oauth.details.name;
        self.token = oauth.token;
        self.authenticated = true;

        var name = window.prompt('who would you like to greet?');

        // <5>
        $http.get('/greetings-service/greet/' + name)
            .success(function (greetingData) {
                self.greetingFromZuulRoute = greetingData.greeting;
            })
            .error(function (e) {
                console.log('oops!' + JSON.stringify(e));
            });

        // <6>
        $http.get('/lets/greet/' + name)
            .success(function (greetingData) {
                self.greetingFromEdgeService = greetingData.greeting;
            })
            .error(function (e) {
                console.log('oops!' + JSON.stringify(e));
            });
    });
});
```

**So it is expected**, that login procedure is initiated and login form appears.

**Actual result:** browser gets redirected to authorization server and hits CORS error

*Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:9191/uaa/oauth/authorize?client_id=html5&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8082/login&response_type=code&state=1zegi7' (redirected from 'http://localhost:8082/user') from origin 'http://localhost:8082' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.*

Here: localhost:8082 - Gateway service, localhost:9191 - authorization server.

In Browser console I can see that was an OPTIONS request.

On the other hand, if I explicitly call */login* endpoint (provided by spring) it works as expected - the login form appears and
after credentials validation I get redirected back to the home page.

Gateway service has simple servlet filter, where I explicitly set ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN header.

```
@Component
class CorsFilter implements Filter {

    private final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = HttpServletResponse.class.cast(res);
        HttpServletRequest request = HttpServletRequest.class.cast(req);

        log.info(request.getMethod());

        response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN, "*");

        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

}
```

**The questions:**

- How to properly handle preflight requests in such case?
- Shouldn't servlet filter handle OPTIONS request? (I do not see it in logs)

**What I have tried:**

- Use explicit servlet filter (shown above)
- Use HttpSecurity.cors() method in conjuction with CorsConfigurationSource bean:

  ```
  @Configuration
  @EnableOAuth2Sso
  class SsoConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

      http.cors().and().antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests()
              .antMatchers( "/", "/app.js", "/login**", "/webjars/**").permitAll().anyRequest()
              .authenticated().and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll().and().csrf()
              .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
  }

  @Bean
  CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
      CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
      configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
      configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
      configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST","OPTIONS"));
      UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
      source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
      return source;
  }
  }
  ```

**UPDATE:** Here are properties I used for SSO gateway:

```
spring.application.name=greetings-client
server.port=${PORT:8082}
security.oauth2.resource.userInfoUri=http://auth-service/uaa/user
spring.mvc.dispatch-options-request=true

zuul.routes.hi.path=/lets/**
zuul.routes.hi.serviceId=greetings-service

management.security.enabled=false

zuul.ignoredServices=*

eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=true
eureka.instance.leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds=10
```

And here are properties for Auth service:

```
server.port=${PORT:9191}
spring.application.name=auth-service
server.context-path=/uaa
security.sessions=if_required
logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true

eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=true
eureka.instance.leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds=10
```

And Authorization server configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends
        AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    private final ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public AuthorizationServerConfiguration(
            AuthenticationManager authenticationManager,
            ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.clientDetailsService = clientDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        // <1>
        clients.withClientDetails(this.clientDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
            throws Exception {
        // <2>
        endpoints.authenticationManager(this.authenticationManager);
    }
}
```

Comment: it clearly says, the call from localhost:8082 to localhost:9191 is affected by cors. Since you havn't told us which is which you need to enable cors on whatever it is running on localhost:9191 i suspect thats the "authorization server" auth-service. Where is that config?

Comment: Hi! Actually I mentioned above, that
localhost:8082 - Gateway service, 
localhost:9191 - authorization server.

Auth server is simple, I added its configuration as well as properties files.

Comment: Well you need to enable cors on it.

Comment: Yes, but I thought there must be a way to handle CORS only on gateway side, is this possible?

Comment: no, when you are redirected, the first server responds with a status of 302 and a header telling where to redirect. In this redirect response there is probably an origin header telling you that the origin is "localhost:8082". 

The call is made to localhost:9191 and as the CORS standard "An origin is defined as a combination of URI scheme, host name, and port number."

You will not have the same origin. So CORS kicks in on localhost:9191 and refuses the request.

Comment: Ok, but what is the difference with an explicit call to /login? Why it works then? In the end it also redirects me to the authorization server.

Comment: it all depends on HOW you are doing your call. If you are doing your call using a browser, the browser will automatically add a lot of headers, like an origin header. Of you are ising something like postman these headers are not sent unless you explicitly send them. Thats why you need to DEBUG. Check in the chrome dev tools what you are actually sending and read up on CORS